# Check if a html input field is empty in java

Tags: java, string

I'm creating a web application by using java ee. I have a doubt. To check correctly if a text field is NOT empty is right to do this check?

```
    if(home_number != null || !(home_number.equals("")))
    {

    }
```

There are also `.isEmpty()` functin and `lenght() > 0` to check if a string is NOT EMPTY. Which is the best way?

Comment: use lenght() > 0 for empty check

Comment: Do you consider a string only containing whitespace characters (`"  "` etc.) to be empty?

Comment: To avoid NPE, you can use `!("".equals(home_number))` instead of `!(home_number.equals("")`

Comment: I have to consider a string empty when the input text field is leaved empty by the user.

Comment: you can use the  `required` Attribute, like `<h:inputText value="#{home_number}" required="true" />`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to handle all the corner cases (what if string is null, what if it is only composed of spaces etc...)  you'll probably be better off using a library that covers that properly for you like Apache commons lang and its `StringUtils` class: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html

And therefore have a more readable code :

```
if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(home_number)) { ...
```

Comment: I have read the apidocs and I have realized that for my case 'isNotBlank()' is the perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

`isEmpty` is more preferable as the documentation said

```
Returns true if, and only if, length() is 0.
```

so if the length is 0 then it will return directly as true.

**vs.** `!(home_number.equals("")`

```
public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
if (this == anObject) {
    return true;
}
if (anObject instanceof String) {
    String anotherString = (String)anObject;
    int n = count;
    if (n == anotherString.count) {
        char v1[] = value;
        char v2[] = anotherString.value;
        int i = offset;
        int j = anotherString.offset;
        while (n-- != 0) {
            if (v1[i++] != v2[j++])
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

You need to trim your string first before checking if its empty
}

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest pattern, in my opinion is:

```
if (a != null && !a.isEmpty()) {
    // ...
}
```

And instead of repeating that hundreds of times, write a small static utility method to wrap this behavior, or use Google Guava's [`Strings.isNullOrEmpty()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Strings.html#isNullOrEmpty%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 0):

You can check if input-field is not empty using `.isEmpty()`, but what if the text-field is filled with **spaces** ???

So, I'll recommend you to use `.trim()` before checking for `empty String` :

```
if(str != null && !(str.trim().isEmpty())){
   // do whatever you want
}
```